Given an ill-looking reinforcement learning performance curve, what are the possible causes?
Given an ill-looking reinforcement learning performance curve, what are the possible causes?
For example, in the graph below, y-axis is return, and x-axis is training epoch, the algorithm (PPO in this case) is able to learn quite well at the beginning (increasing return), but somehow it starts to "unlearn" afterwards...


I would guess this curve is for PPO during training, and not separate test/validation runs with tweaks to exploration parameters? That's worth making clear because expected behaviour for many RL algorithms will differ between training and test runs, but a lot of people don't bother with separate automated testing during training (not saying you should, and I don't know enough about PPO to know if it would help)

Do you have any details of the environment that you can share? That may help. An upper bound on the return could also help, and some indication of how stochastic the environment is

Please, provide more details about the curves. You even occluded the legend, for some mysterious reason. Maybe this is a homework problem?
